# Wrong syntax highlighting halfway through a Python identifier

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

**Update**: This is actually a bug with highlight.js, but I was testing with an older version that didn't have the problem. I submitted [a bug report](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3378).

---

Syntax highlighting changes halfway through a Python identifier `_undef` to look like the `def` keyword.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of code showing the problem]

The code itself:

```py
foo = _undef
bar
```

I can't reproduce the issue in [a highlight.js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pa3rjc6/2/) (forked from [the official fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajoshguy/2bmdswn6/)), so it seems like Stack Exchange needs to update. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the fiddle without the problem]

### More info

- I noticed the problem "in the wild" on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642235/4518341).
- The HTML output:

  ```html
  <pre class="lang-py s-code-block"><code class="hljs language-python">foo = _un<span class="hljs-keyword">def</span>
  <span class="hljs-title function_">bar</span>
  </code></pre>
  ```
- The issue doesn't occur when the identifier is followed by a different token, like a literal:

  ```py
  foo = _undef
  []
  ```
- For comparison, here's GitHub:

  [image: screenshot of GitHub without the issue]

  Most other syntax highlighters simply don't highlight anything.
- Per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274372/4518341), I'm submitting this as a feature request instead of a bug.

Comment: This is a bug in highlight.js. It can be duplicated [in your highlight.js fiddle by setting the version of highlight.js to the version which SE uses, 11.0.1, rather than the version, 10.7.1, with which you are currently testing](https://jsfiddle.net/c478vqpm/). It can be reported to highlight.js as [an issue on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues).

Comment: @Makyen Oh, I see! I assumed the fiddle was using the latest version. The issue also occurs with the latest, 11.3.1, so it looks like I'll be filing a bug report. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641955/elegant-way-to-remove-contiguous-repeated-elements-in-a-list/7642235#7642235).

Comment: Related (but completely different reason (web browser bug)): *[Syntax highlighter gives up mid-word](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404071/)*

Comment: @Peter That's the same example I linked...?