# What's wrong with this CSS code so syntax highlighting seems to break?

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

As for the closing/re-opening: a) my question is about grid properties breaking the CSS rendering, not about CSS custom properties causing a comparable issue; b) the duplicate doesn't even have any answers and no helpful reactions.

The following CSS snippet in a [Stack Overflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69893033/3744304) currently seems to have broken syntax highlighting.

```css
.grid_body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 17.5px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(400px, auto);
  row-gap: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 17.5px;
  align-items: start;
}
```

renders as the following in the snippet preview

[image]

and as the following in the snippet editor

[image]

From what I know, the syntax is perfectly fine. Is the CSS syntax highlighter broken?

Comment: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3308

Comment: According to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412707/wrong-syntax-highlighting-halfway-through-a-python-identifier#comment876626_412707) a few days ago (Oct 30) SE was still using 11.0.1 The fix made it in 11.3.1, so simply updating SE's version should be enough, as for when this will happen, I have no idea.